# JSF navigation problem

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Currently i  updating a jsf project and a realize a strange thing about project when a jsf page get a request and page returned  to client i see page completely in browser after this a new request to same page arrives despite the fact i didnt click any thing i am using navigation handler for navigation.I am using jsf(myfaces),richfaces in my project.

i set two break points on these class and i see most of the pages ,not all ,sent request and request goes through menufilter -> myfacesservletwrapper (at that point browser shows page completly)after this menufilter break a nother request for same page .

```
package com.endersys.itap.ui;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.endersys.itap.ui.module.user.User;
import com.endersys.itap.ui.module.user.UserManager;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class MenuFilter implements Filter {

    private String ALLOWED = "login.xhtml";
    private String ALLOWED_FOLDER = "a4j";


    private static boolean searchEnabled = false;
    private static boolean syslogServiceEnabled = false;
    private static String SYSLOG_PAGE= "syslogsettings.xhtml";
    private Properties conf;
    private String SEARCH_PAGE= "search.xhtml";

    private static final String BASE_PATH = "/opt/itap/logmonitor/";
    private static final String CONF_PATH = BASE_PATH + "etc/logmonitor.properties";

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MenuFilter.class.getName());

    public void destroy() {
    }

     public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        if(loadConfiguration())
        {
            if(conf.getProperty("search_enabled").equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
                searchEnabled = true;
            }

            try
            {
                if(conf.getProperty("syslog_enabled").equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                {
                    syslogServiceEnabled = true;
                }
            }catch(Exception exc)
            {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean loadConfiguration()
    {
        conf = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(CONF_PATH);
            conf.load(fis);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

     /**
     * TODO Unit test this function extensively.
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try
        {
            UserManager userManager = (UserManager) ((HttpServletRequest) req)
                    .getSession(true).getAttribute("userManager");

            // http://localhost:8080/itapgui-v2*/index.xhtml*
            String relativePath = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getServletPath();
            // Servlet path has a leading "/" but our menu items do not.
            relativePath = relativePath.substring(1);

            // http://localhost:8080*/itapgui-v2*/index.xhtml
            String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getContextPath();

            if(!searchEnabled && relativePath.endsWith(SEARCH_PAGE))
            {
                ((HttpServletResponse) res).sendRedirect(contextPath
                            + "/index.xhtml");
                return;
            }

            if(!syslogServiceEnabled && relativePath.endsWith(SYSLOG_PAGE))
            {
                ((HttpServletResponse) res).sendRedirect(contextPath
                            + "/index.xhtml");
                return;
            }

            if (!relativePath.endsWith(ALLOWED)
                    && !relativePath.startsWith(ALLOWED_FOLDER)) {
                // Permission required.
                // if (relativePath.endsWith("logout.xhtml")) {
                // ((HttpServletRequest) req).getSession(true).invalidate();
                // ((HttpServletResponse) res).sendRedirect(contextPath
                // + "/login.xhtml");
                // return; // Required.
                // }

                if (userManager == null) {
                    // Not authorized.
                    if(relativePath != null && relativePath.endsWith("index.xhtml"))
                    {
                         ((HttpServletResponse) res).sendRedirect(contextPath
                            + "/login.xhtml");
                    }else
                    {
                    ((HttpServletResponse) res).sendRedirect(contextPath
                            + "/login.xhtml?session=expired");
                    }
                    return; // Required.
                }
                User user = userManager.getUser();
                if (user.getId() == null) {
                    // Not authorized.
                    ((HttpServletResponse) res).sendRedirect(contextPath
                            + "/login.xhtml");
                    return; // Required.
                } else if (user.getId() != 1) {
                    Menu menu = (Menu) ((HttpServletRequest) req).getSession(true)
                            .getAttribute("menu");
                    MenuItem item = menu.getItemByPath(relativePath);
                    if(item != null)
                    {
                        if (!userManager.access(item.getPerms())) {
                            ((HttpServletResponse) res).sendRedirect(contextPath
                                    + "/error.xhtml");
                            return; // Required.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            chain.doFilter((HttpServletRequest) req, (HttpServletResponse) res);

        }catch(Exception exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();

            if(exc instanceof IOException)
            {
                throw (IOException) exc;
            }
            else if(exc instanceof ServletException)
            {
                throw (ServletException) exc;
            }

        }
    }



}





public class MyFacesServletWrapper extends MyFacesServlet {

    private static final String CONN_ERROR_URI = "/dberror.xhtml";
    private static final String OTHER_ERROR_URI = "/errors.xhtml";

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            super.service(request, response);

        } catch (ServletException e) {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

            //if an database exception has occured
            if (ExceptionUtils.indexOfType(e, javax.persistence.PersistenceException.class) != -1) {
                res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + CONN_ERROR_URI);
            }
            else {
                // add the exception to the session scope attribute
                // to show stack trace
                req.getSession().setAttribute("exception", e);
                res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + OTHER_ERROR_URI);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I still have not solved problem but i think it result from richfaces .But i am not sure ,any one has deep knowledge about richfaces and ajax can be great help.

Comment: It is difficult to say. There are lots of reasons why richfaces may be making two requests. I would guess that there are multiple requests coming from the client and it isn't an issue in your servlet or filter. I may misunderstand your English though.

Comment: Is it possible two sent two  request when i click someaction source.For example if there is a page which has a form inside another form

Comment: It is possible. I've often seen it as a result of combining "oncomplete" and "rerender" tags with some javascript rerendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the conversation in the comments I would suggest you look into the details of the JSF lifecycle. Keep in mind that any `reRender`ing or `ajaxRendred="true"` might kick off the lifecycle. This site has been very helpful for me in the past: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/

Answer (score 0):

Richfaces components   sending request to server ,i trace them to a4j servlet